# Какое есть расширение VSCode с подсказками кода React?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, расширения

Какое есть расширение VSCode с подсказками кода React?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужны сниппеты, то https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets
Если нужен автокомплит, мне понравилась Codeium